# Error after 'hub create' cmd for a new rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, terminal, rubygems

I created a new rails app with the 'rails new' command line, then tried to create the repo on GitHub with my 'hub create' gem command as usual, but got this response in terminal :

```
Ignoring bcrypt-3.1.11 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bcrypt --version 3.1.11
Ignoring binding_of_caller-0.7.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine binding_of_caller --version 0.7.2
Ignoring byebug-9.0.5 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine byebug --version 9.0.5
Ignoring curb-0.9.3 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine curb --version 0.9.3
Ignoring debug_inspector-0.0.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine debug_inspector --version 0.0.2
/usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:308:in `to_specs': Could not find 'hub' (>= 0.a) among 122 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/OSX/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0:/Users/OSX/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global', execute `gem env` for more information
from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:320:in `to_spec'
from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:65:in `gem'
from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/hub:22:in `<main>'
```

So I tried the 'gem pristine' commands but nothing changed. I uninstalled then reinstalled ruby, rails, updated my gems, made a 'brew uninstall hub' then reinstalled, but this response still appears! I also tried to create a new rails app in 4.2.0 since I thought maybe that would be some rails 5 compatibility issue, but no, same message.

My hub command worked perfectly fine a few weeks ago, I cannot figure how to fix this. If you have any idea...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I figured it out, I just had to :

```
gem install hub
```

But I thought I had hub installed with brew, and my hub commands worked a few weeks ago, so I'm missing something here...

However now it works !